# Invalid Page Redirection error for html input type file saving as attachment

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have below page snippet that throws error as in header.

**Apex Page Snippet:**
           **Save**

```
     <script>
   var blobfile;
   function getAsText(readFile) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(readFile);
    reader.onload = attLoaded;
   }
   function attLoaded(evt) {  
    var fileString = evt.target.result;
    alert('fileString @' + fileString );
    blobfile = fileString;
    var  input = document.getElementById("fileId");
    alert('input@' + input);
    var filename= input.value;          
    actfun(filename,blobfile);
   }
   function remoteLocationPost(){
     alert('fbody@' + document.getElementById("fileId"));
    var fbody= document.getElementById("fileId").files[0];

    getAsText(fbody); 
   }   
  </script>

       <apex:outputPanel id="out">
    <apex:outputText value=""/>
    <apex:actionstatus id="actStatusId">
                        <apex:facet name="start">
                            <div class="waitingSearchDiv" id="el_loading" style="background-color: #DCD6D6; height: 120%;opacity:0.65;width:120%;"> 
                                <div class="waitingHolder" style="top: 74.2px; width: 91px;">
                                    <img class="waitingImage" src="/img/loading.gif" title="Please Wait..." />
                                    <span class="waitingDescription">Please wait...</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </apex:facet>
     </apex:actionstatus>
    </apex:outputPanel>
```

As in console I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.
```

Answer (score 1):

What's the value of document.getElementById("fileId").files[0]; in remoteLocationPost?  Unless there's some code that isn't here, it looks like it's null.  If that's true, then you're passing a null value to FileReader.readAsDataURL, when it's expecting a Blob.

Comment: Yes it is null. How to deal with? What do I need to pass? Can you please help?

Comment: Well...there is no element in your markup with an id = "fileId".   It doesn't get much more null than that!   ;)

Comment: But I am having an html input type="file" id="fileId" in the page. Shall I keep it inside this outputpanel to get it accessed? The input file is working fine to upload the attachment file currently.

Comment: Ah. It's not in the part you posted. Go ahead and pay the rest of your code.